# What is the meaning of gcc command

Tags: command-line, gcc

I wonder what does the command
`gcc -o sample sample.c` really means and what it does in the system.

I know `gcc` is the command to invoke gcc compiler, but what does -o and filename(without extension) followed by filename(with extension) means here.

Comment: `gcc -o sample sample.c` compiles the C code in `sample.c` to an executable binary `sample`, which you can run by typing `./sample`. The `-o` flag sets the name of the **o**utput file, `sample.c` is the source code file.

Comment: Apart from -o what are the other flags we can set?

Comment: there are lots. You can see them all by running `man gcc` in a Terminal.

Comment: @Selvaperumal - is your question answered?  If so - feel free to mark the related answer as accepted. Or do you still need more information? Greetings.

Answer (score 3):

### Your question

What `gcc -o sample sample.c` actually does

The command you have pasted triggers `gcc` to compile `sample.c`. 
As a result you'll get an output/executable with the same `sample`.

The parameters (as -o in your example which defined the name of the output file ) are explained in the man page of gcc.
You can open it by running `man gcc`

I am quoting the `-o` section of the man page here

> -o file
>
> ```
>        Place output in file file.  This applies to whatever sort of output
>        is being produced, whether it be an executable file, an object
>        file, an assembler file or preprocessed C code.
>
>        If -o is not specified, the default is to put an executable file in
>        a.out, the object file for source.suffix in source.o, its assembler
>        file in source.s, a precompiled header file in source.suffix.gch,
>        and all preprocessed C source on standard output.
> ```

### In General

Wikipedia explains a good amount of gcc [here](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/GNU_Compiler_Collection).

I am quoting only the start - but the complete article is worth a read and offers a lot of additional links and references

> The GNU Compiler Collection (GCC) is a compiler system produced by the
>   GNU Project supporting various programming languages. GCC is a key
>   component of the GNU toolchain. The Free Software Foundation (FSF)
>   distributes GCC under the GNU General Public License (GNU GPL). GCC
>   has played an important role in the growth of free software, as both a
>   tool and an example.
>
> Originally named the GNU C Compiler, when it only handled the C
>   programming language, GCC 1.0 was released in 1987. It was extended
>   to compile C++ in December of that year. Front ends were later
>   developed for Objective-C, Objective-C++, Fortran, Java, Ada, and Go
>   among others.
>
> GCC has been ported to a wide variety of processor architectures, and
>   is widely deployed as a tool in the development of both free and
>   proprietary software. GCC is also available for most embedded
>   platforms,[citation needed] including Symbian (called gcce), AMCC,
>   and Freescale Power Architecture-based chips. The compiler can
>   target a wide variety of platforms, including video game consoles such
>   as the PlayStation 2 and Dreamcast.
>
> As well as being the official compiler of the GNU operating system,
>   GCC has been adopted as the standard compiler by many other modern
>   Unix-like computer operating systems, including Linux and the BSD
>   family, although FreeBSD and OS X have moved to the LLVM system.
>   Versions are also available for Microsoft Windows and other operating
>   systems; GCC can compile code for Android and iOS.

Comment: I would advise you to include the most important information from the Wikipedia link in case it ever breaks.

Comment: Added the starting portion - but to be honest - if Wikipedia breaks - i doubt AskUbuntu still exists ;)

Comment: Me too, actually, but it's generally advised to include the most important information from links in your answer

Comment: It would be good to include the relevant part of the manpage for `-o`

Comment: good point - i've added the -o section from the man page

Answer (score 1):

`GCC` is GNU C (language) compiler. It's used to "convert" programs written in C programming language into binary executable on computer.

The syntax `gcc -o sample sample.c` means:
Compile the file sample.c and name the output sample.

Then you can launch your compiled program with `<path_to_file>/sample`, or from within the directory `./sample`

The default name for compiled program is `a.out`, so with `-o` parameter you can specify your desired output name.

Comment: Apart from -o what are the other flags we can set? –

Comment: There are many, run `man gcc` in your terminal.